# Oracle Precompiler dll library

Tags: oracle, dll, oracle-pro-c

Platform : Windows running Oracle 10g

I have to modify some old dll library codes and precompile with Oracle
Pro*C/C++ 9.0.1.1.1, now I discovered the codes 
for(;;) whenever not found do break is no longer working, it just keep
looping.
I have prepared some codes here showing before and after precompile and
also a log.
Thanks in advance to whoever might be able to help.

```
(A) the PC program 

/************************************************************************/ 
/* fmt_clnt.pc                                                          */ 
/************************************************************************/ 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <process.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h> 
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
 | Copyright (c) Oracle Corporation 1993.  All Rights Reserved, Worldwide.  | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | NAME                                                                     | 
 |   ue.h - User Exit Functions Header File.                                | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | FUNCTION                                                                 | 
 |    Define the exitr structure. Misc defines.                             | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | CONTENTS                                                                 | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | NOTES                                                                    | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | MODIFIED                                                                 | 
 |  KMajkut  03/23/93 Created. Split off from old ue.h                      | 
 |                    Added definition of exitr from usrxit.h               | 
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

#ifndef UE 
#define UE 

#define MAX_ERRBUF_SIZE    256 

extern char  SRWERB[]; 

struct  exitr                           /* Struct definition for exits */ 
{ 
         char     *exnam;               /* Name of the user exit */ 
         int       (*exfp)(/*_ char* _*/);   /* Pointer to exit routine */ 
         int       extyp;               /* Type code for exit routine  */ 
#define  XITCC1    1                    /* C (for existing exits)      */ 
#define  XITCC     2                    /* C (call-by-reference)       */ 
#define  XITCOB    3                    /* Cobol                      */ 
#define  XITFOR    4                    /* Fortran                    */ 
#define  XITPLI    5                    /* PL/I                             */ 
#define  XITPAS    6                    /* Pascal                           */ 
#define  XITAda    7                    /* Ada                              */ 
}; 

/* Failure and Success return codes */ 
#define    FATAL_ERR  535    /* Use this on really bad errors */ 
#define    FAILURE  1403   /* Use this on recoverable error */ 
#define    SUCCESS  0      /* Use for success */ 

typedef struct exitr exitr; 

extern exitr iapxtb[]; 


#endif /* UE */ 

#define NORMAL      0 
#define HYFAILED      1 


# define externdef globaldef 


extern int fmt_clnt(); 
extern int inv_msp(); 
extern int inv_ism(); 
extern int readmsp(); 
extern int coll_bad(); 
/*******************************************************************/ 
exec sql begin declare section; 
char   frm_batch_str[10]; 
int    status; 
long   batch; 
long   todays_batch; 
int    loopcnt; 
char   sub_code[2]; 
char   description[61]; 

exec sql end declare section; 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/* exec sql INCLUDE sqlca; */ 

#ifndef    SQLCODE 
struct     sqlca 
{ 
           unsigned char  sqlcaid[8]; 
           long           sqlcabc; 
           long           sqlcode; 
           short          sqlerrml; 
           unsigned char  sqlerrmc[70]; 
           unsigned char  sqlerrp[8]; 
           long           sqlerrd[6]; 
           unsigned char  sqlwarn[11]; 
           unsigned char  sqlstate[5]; 
}; 
#define      SQLCODE   sqlca.sqlcode 
#define      SQLWARN0  sqlca.sqlwarn[0] 
#define      SQLWARN1  sqlca.sqlwarn[1] 
#define      SQLWARN2  sqlca.sqlwarn[2] 
#define      SQLWARN3  sqlca.sqlwarn[3] 
#define      SQLWARN4  sqlca.sqlwarn[4] 
#define      SQLWARN5  sqlca.sqlwarn[5] 
#define      SQLWARN6  sqlca.sqlwarn[6] 
#define      SQLWARN7  sqlca.sqlwarn[7] 
#define      SQLWARN8  sqlca.sqlwarn[8] 
#define      SQLWARN9  sqlca.sqlwarn[9] 
#define      SQLWARNA  sqlca.sqlwarn[10] 
#define      SQLSTATE  sqlca.sqlstate 
#endif 
struct sqlca sqlca; 

/********************************************/ 

FILE   *logfp; 
int    sql_err(); 
int    call_sqlca_flags (); 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                         Main program                            */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
int fmt_clnt() 
{         
   int i = 1; 
   int status = 0; 
   logfp = fopen("format.txt", "w"); 
   fprintf(logfp, "fmt_clnt version is HY2009Q4\n"); 
   strcpy(frm_batch_str, " "); 
   /****************************************************/ 
   /* get batch number from Forms program              */ 
   /****************************************************/ 
   /* exec iaf get reqdata.batch into :frm_batch_str;  */ 
   exec tools get reqdata.batch into :frm_batch_str;  
   /*****************************************************/ 
   /* Make sure dbms is accessible                      */ 
   /*****************************************************/ 
   exec sql whenever sqlerror do sql_err("Debug 1\n");  
   exec sql select max(batch) into :todays_batch from bill_test; 
   fprintf(logfp, "High batch is %d\n", todays_batch); 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                         For Loop Debug                          */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
   fprintf(logfp, "Only 8 entries in table but will loop forever\n"); 
   fprintf(logfp, "For (;;) loop change to max 20 to force breaking out\n"); 
   exec sql declare c1 cursor for 
       select sub_code, description from submission_code where 1=1 order by sub_code; 
   exec sql OPEN c1; 
   exec sql whenever not found do break; 
   for (i; i < 20 ; ++ i) 
      { 
      exec sql fetch c1 into :sub_code, :description; 
      fprintf(logfp, "When i=%d sqlcode=%d sub_code=%s desc=%s\n", i,sqlca.sqlcode,sub_code,description);  
      } 
   exec sql CLOSE c1; 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                       End For Loop Debug                        */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
   if (status == HYFAILED || status == IAPFAIL)  
      return (IAPFAIL); 
   fclose(logfp); 
   return (IAPSUCC); 
} 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                       SQL_ERR trapping                          */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
int sql_err(msg) 
char *msg; 
{ 
char err_msg[128]; 
int  msg_len;     
/*hy   strcpy (err_msg, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);  */ 
   msg_len = strlen (err_msg); 
   fprintf(logfp, "error %s\n", err_msg); 
   exec sql ROLLBACK; 
   return (IAPFAIL); 
} 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 



(B) the C program after the precompile 

/* Result Sets Interface */ 
#ifndef SQL_CRSR 
#  define SQL_CRSR 
  struct sql_cursor 
  { 
    unsigned int curocn; 
    void *ptr1; 
    void *ptr2; 
    unsigned long magic; 
  }; 
  typedef struct sql_cursor sql_cursor; 
  typedef struct sql_cursor SQL_CURSOR; 
#endif /* SQL_CRSR */ 

/* Thread Safety */ 
typedef void * sql_context; 
typedef void * SQL_CONTEXT; 

/* Object support */ 
struct sqltvn 
{ 
  unsigned char *tvnvsn; 
  unsigned short tvnvsnl; 
  unsigned char *tvnnm; 
  unsigned short tvnnml; 
  unsigned char *tvnsnm; 
  unsigned short tvnsnml; 
}; 
typedef struct sqltvn sqltvn; 

struct sqladts 
{ 
  unsigned int adtvsn; 
  unsigned short adtmode; 
  unsigned short adtnum;  
  sqltvn adttvn[1];       
}; 
typedef struct sqladts sqladts; 

static struct sqladts sqladt = { 
  1,1,0, 
}; 

/* Binding to PL/SQL Records */ 
struct sqltdss 
{ 
  unsigned int tdsvsn; 
  unsigned short tdsnum; 
  unsigned char *tdsval[1]; 
}; 
typedef struct sqltdss sqltdss; 
static struct sqltdss sqltds = 
{ 
  1, 
  0, 
}; 


static char sqh000[] = "REQDATA.BATCH"; 
/* File name & Package Name */ 
struct sqlcxp 
{ 
  unsigned short fillen; 
           char  filnam[22]; 
}; 
static const struct sqlcxp sqlfpn = 
{ 
    21, 
    "C:\\puzzle\\FMT_CLNT.PC" 
}; 


static unsigned long sqlctx = 146507995; 


static struct sqlexd { 
   unsigned int   sqlvsn; 
   unsigned int   arrsiz; 
   unsigned int   iters; 
   unsigned int   offset; 
   unsigned short selerr; 
   unsigned short sqlety; 
   unsigned int   occurs; 
      const short *cud; 
   unsigned char  *sqlest; 
      const char  *stmt; 
   sqladts *sqladtp; 
   sqltdss *sqltdsp; 
            void  **sqphsv; 
   unsigned int   *sqphsl; 
            int   *sqphss; 
            void  **sqpind; 
            int   *sqpins; 
   unsigned int   *sqparm; 
   unsigned int   **sqparc; 
   unsigned short  *sqpadto; 
   unsigned short  *sqptdso; 
            void  *sqhstv[2]; 
   unsigned int   sqhstl[2]; 
            int   sqhsts[2]; 
            void  *sqindv[2]; 
            int   sqinds[2]; 
   unsigned int   sqharm[2]; 
   unsigned int   *sqharc[2]; 
   unsigned short  sqadto[2]; 
   unsigned short  sqtdso[2]; 
} sqlstm = {10,2}; 

/* SQLLIB Prototypes */ 
extern void sqlcxt (void **, unsigned long *, 
                    struct sqlexd *, const struct sqlcxp *); 
extern void sqlcx2t(void **, unsigned long *, 
                    struct sqlexd *, const struct sqlcxp *); 
extern void sqlbuft(void **, char *); 
extern void sqlgs2t(void **, char *); 
extern void sqlorat(void **, unsigned long *, void *); 

/* Forms Interface */ 
static const int IAPSUCC = 0; 
static const int IAPFAIL = 1403; 
static const int IAPFTL  = 535; 
extern void sqliem(char *, int *); 

 static const char *sq0003 = 
"select sub_code ,description  from submission_code where 1=1 order by sub_co\ 
de            "; 

typedef struct { unsigned short len; unsigned char arr[1]; } VARCHAR; 
typedef struct { unsigned short len; unsigned char arr[1]; } varchar; 

/* cud (compilation unit data) array */ 
static const short sqlcud0[] = 
{10,4130,178,0,0, 
5,0,0,1,0,0,51,152,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,2,97,0,0, 
28,0,0,2,43,0,4,157,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,3,0,0, 
47,0,0,3,90,0,9,168,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 
62,0,0,3,0,0,13,172,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,2,97,0,0,2,97,0,0, 
85,0,0,3,0,0,15,175,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 
100,0,0,4,0,0,31,200,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 
}; 


/************************************************************************/ 
/* fmt_clnt.pc                                                          */ 
/************************************************************************/ 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <process.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h> 
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
 | Copyright (c) Oracle Corporation 1993.  All Rights Reserved, Worldwide.  | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | NAME                                                                     | 
 |   ue.h - User Exit Functions Header File.                                | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | FUNCTION                                                                 | 
 |    Define the exitr structure. Misc defines.                             | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | CONTENTS                                                                 | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | NOTES                                                                    | 
 |                                                                          | 
 | MODIFIED                                                                 | 
 |  KMajkut  03/23/93 Created. Split off from old ue.h                      | 
 |                    Added definition of exitr from usrxit.h               | 
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

#ifndef UE 
#define UE 

#define MAX_ERRBUF_SIZE    256 

extern char  SRWERB[]; 

struct  exitr                           /* Struct definition for exits */ 
{ 
         char     *exnam;               /* Name of the user exit */ 
         int       (*exfp)(/*_ char* _*/);   /* Pointer to exit routine */ 
         int       extyp;               /* Type code for exit routine  */ 
#define  XITCC1    1                    /* C (for existing exits)      */ 
#define  XITCC     2                    /* C (call-by-reference)       */ 
#define  XITCOB    3                    /* Cobol                      */ 
#define  XITFOR    4                    /* Fortran                    */ 
#define  XITPLI    5                    /* PL/I                             */ 
#define  XITPAS    6                    /* Pascal                           */ 
#define  XITAda    7                    /* Ada                              */ 
}; 

/* Failure and Success return codes */ 
#define    FATAL_ERR  535    /* Use this on really bad errors */ 
#define    FAILURE  1403   /* Use this on recoverable error */ 
#define    SUCCESS  0      /* Use for success */ 

typedef struct exitr exitr; 

extern exitr iapxtb[]; 


#endif /* UE */ 

#define NORMAL      0 
#define HYFAILED      1 


# define externdef globaldef 


extern int fmt_clnt(); 
extern int inv_msp(); 
extern int inv_ism(); 
extern int readmsp(); 
extern int coll_bad(); 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/* exec sql begin declare section; */ 

char   frm_batch_str[10]; 
int    status; 
long   batch; 
long   todays_batch; 
int    loopcnt; 
char   sub_code[2]; 
char   description[61]; 

/* exec sql end declare section; */ 

/*******************************************************************/ 
/* exec sql INCLUDE sqlca; */ 

#ifndef    SQLCODE 
struct     sqlca 
{ 
           unsigned char  sqlcaid[8]; 
           long           sqlcabc; 
           long           sqlcode; 
           short          sqlerrml; 
           unsigned char  sqlerrmc[70]; 
           unsigned char  sqlerrp[8]; 
           long           sqlerrd[6]; 
           unsigned char  sqlwarn[11]; 
           unsigned char  sqlstate[5]; 
}; 
#define      SQLCODE   sqlca.sqlcode 
#define      SQLWARN0  sqlca.sqlwarn[0] 
#define      SQLWARN1  sqlca.sqlwarn[1] 
#define      SQLWARN2  sqlca.sqlwarn[2] 
#define      SQLWARN3  sqlca.sqlwarn[3] 
#define      SQLWARN4  sqlca.sqlwarn[4] 
#define      SQLWARN5  sqlca.sqlwarn[5] 
#define      SQLWARN6  sqlca.sqlwarn[6] 
#define      SQLWARN7  sqlca.sqlwarn[7] 
#define      SQLWARN8  sqlca.sqlwarn[8] 
#define      SQLWARN9  sqlca.sqlwarn[9] 
#define      SQLWARNA  sqlca.sqlwarn[10] 
#define      SQLSTATE  sqlca.sqlstate 
#endif 
struct sqlca sqlca; 

/********************************************/ 

FILE   *logfp; 
int    sql_err(); 
int    call_sqlca_flags (); 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                         Main program                            */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
int fmt_clnt() 
{         
   int i = 1; 
   int status = 0; 
   logfp = fopen("format.txt", "w"); 
   fprintf(logfp, "fmt_clnt version is HY2009Q4\n"); 
   strcpy(frm_batch_str, " "); 
   /****************************************************/ 
   /* get batch number from Forms program              */ 
   /****************************************************/ 
   /* exec iaf get reqdata.batch into :frm_batch_str;  */ 
   /* exec tools get reqdata.batch into :frm_batch_str; */ 

{ 
   struct sqlexd sqlstm; 
   sqlstm.sqlvsn = 10; 
   sqlstm.arrsiz = 2; 
   sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt; 
   sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds; 
   sqlstm.stmt = ""; 
   sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1; 
   sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )5; 
   sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0; 
   sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca; 
   sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)256; 
   sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqhstv[0] = (         void  *)sqh000; 
   sqlstm.sqhstl[0] = (unsigned int  )13; 
   sqlstm.sqhsts[0] = (         int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqindv[0] = (         void  *)0; 
   sqlstm.sqinds[0] = (         int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqharm[0] = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqadto[0] = (unsigned short )0; 
   sqlstm.sqtdso[0] = (unsigned short )0; 
   sqlstm.sqhstv[1] = (         void  *)frm_batch_str; 
   sqlstm.sqhstl[1] = (unsigned int  )10; 
   sqlstm.sqhsts[1] = (         int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqindv[1] = (         void  *)0; 
   sqlstm.sqinds[1] = (         int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqharm[1] = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqadto[1] = (unsigned short )0; 
   sqlstm.sqtdso[1] = (unsigned short )0; 
   sqlstm.sqphsv = sqlstm.sqhstv; 
   sqlstm.sqphsl = sqlstm.sqhstl; 
   sqlstm.sqphss = sqlstm.sqhsts; 
   sqlstm.sqpind = sqlstm.sqindv; 
   sqlstm.sqpins = sqlstm.sqinds; 
   sqlstm.sqparm = sqlstm.sqharm; 
   sqlstm.sqparc = sqlstm.sqharc; 
   sqlstm.sqpadto = sqlstm.sqadto; 
   sqlstm.sqptdso = sqlstm.sqtdso; 
   sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn); 
} 


   /*****************************************************/ 
   /* Make sure dbms is accessible                      */ 
   /*****************************************************/ 
   /* exec sql whenever sqlerror do sql_err("Debug 1\n"); */ 

   /* exec sql select max(batch) into :todays_batch from bill_test; */ 

{ 
   struct sqlexd sqlstm; 
   sqlstm.sqlvsn = 10; 
   sqlstm.arrsiz = 2; 
   sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt; 
   sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds; 
   sqlstm.stmt = "select max(batch) into :b0  from bill_test "; 
   sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1; 
   sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )28; 
   sqlstm.selerr = (unsigned short)1; 
   sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0; 
   sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca; 
   sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)256; 
   sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqhstv[0] = (         void  *)&todays_batch; 
   sqlstm.sqhstl[0] = (unsigned int  )sizeof(long); 
   sqlstm.sqhsts[0] = (         int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqindv[0] = (         void  *)0; 
   sqlstm.sqinds[0] = (         int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqharm[0] = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlstm.sqadto[0] = (unsigned short )0; 
   sqlstm.sqtdso[0] = (unsigned short )0; 
   sqlstm.sqphsv = sqlstm.sqhstv; 
   sqlstm.sqphsl = sqlstm.sqhstl; 
   sqlstm.sqphss = sqlstm.sqhsts; 
   sqlstm.sqpind = sqlstm.sqindv; 
   sqlstm.sqpins = sqlstm.sqinds; 
   sqlstm.sqparm = sqlstm.sqharm; 
   sqlstm.sqparc = sqlstm.sqharc; 
   sqlstm.sqpadto = sqlstm.sqadto; 
   sqlstm.sqptdso = sqlstm.sqtdso; 
   sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn); 
   if (sqlca.sqlcode < 0) sql_err("Debug 1\n"); 
} 


   fprintf(logfp, "High batch is %d\n", todays_batch); 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                         For Loop Debug                          */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
   fprintf(logfp, "Only 8 entries in table but will loop forever\n"); 
   fprintf(logfp, "For (;;) loop change to max 20 to force breaking out\n"); 
   /* exec sql declare c1 cursor for 
       select sub_code, description from submission_code where 1=1 order by sub_code; */ 

   /* exec sql OPEN c1; */ 

{ 
   struct sqlexd sqlstm; 
   sqlstm.sqlvsn = 10; 
   sqlstm.arrsiz = 2; 
   sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt; 
   sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds; 
   sqlstm.stmt = sq0003; 
   sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1; 
   sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )47; 
   sqlstm.selerr = (unsigned short)1; 
   sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0; 
   sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca; 
   sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)256; 
   sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn); 
   if (sqlca.sqlcode < 0) sql_err("Debug 1\n"); 
} 


   /* exec sql whenever not found do break; */ 

   for (i; i < 20 ; ++ i) 
      { 
      /* exec sql fetch c1 into :sub_code, :description; */ 

{ 
      struct sqlexd sqlstm; 
      sqlstm.sqlvsn = 10; 
      sqlstm.arrsiz = 2; 
      sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt; 
      sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds; 
      sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1; 
      sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )62; 
      sqlstm.selerr = (unsigned short)1; 
      sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0; 
      sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca; 
      sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)256; 
      sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0; 
      sqlstm.sqhstv[0] = (         void  *)sub_code; 
      sqlstm.sqhstl[0] = (unsigned int  )2; 
      sqlstm.sqhsts[0] = (         int  )0; 
      sqlstm.sqindv[0] = (         void  *)0; 
      sqlstm.sqinds[0] = (         int  )0; 
      sqlstm.sqharm[0] = (unsigned int  )0; 
      sqlstm.sqadto[0] = (unsigned short )0; 
      sqlstm.sqtdso[0] = (unsigned short )0; 
      sqlstm.sqhstv[1] = (         void  *)description; 
      sqlstm.sqhstl[1] = (unsigned int  )61; 
      sqlstm.sqhsts[1] = (         int  )0; 
      sqlstm.sqindv[1] = (         void  *)0; 
      sqlstm.sqinds[1] = (         int  )0; 
      sqlstm.sqharm[1] = (unsigned int  )0; 
      sqlstm.sqadto[1] = (unsigned short )0; 
      sqlstm.sqtdso[1] = (unsigned short )0; 
      sqlstm.sqphsv = sqlstm.sqhstv; 
      sqlstm.sqphsl = sqlstm.sqhstl; 
      sqlstm.sqphss = sqlstm.sqhsts; 
      sqlstm.sqpind = sqlstm.sqindv; 
      sqlstm.sqpins = sqlstm.sqinds; 
      sqlstm.sqparm = sqlstm.sqharm; 
      sqlstm.sqparc = sqlstm.sqharc; 
      sqlstm.sqpadto = sqlstm.sqadto; 
      sqlstm.sqptdso = sqlstm.sqtdso; 
      sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn); 
      if (sqlca.sqlcode == 1403) break; 
      if (sqlca.sqlcode < 0) sql_err("Debug 1\n"); 
} 


      fprintf(logfp, "When i=%d sqlcode=%d sub_code=%s desc=%s\n", i,sqlca.sqlcode,sub_code,description);  
      } 
   /* exec sql CLOSE c1; */ 

{ 
   struct sqlexd sqlstm; 
   sqlstm.sqlvsn = 10; 
   sqlstm.arrsiz = 2; 
   sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt; 
   sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds; 
   sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1; 
   sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )85; 
   sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0; 
   sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca; 
   sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)256; 
   sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn); 
   if (sqlca.sqlcode < 0) sql_err("Debug 1\n"); 
} 


/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                       End For Loop Debug                        */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
   if (status == HYFAILED || status == IAPFAIL)  
      return (IAPFAIL); 
   fclose(logfp); 
   return (IAPSUCC); 
} 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*                       SQL_ERR trapping                          */ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 
int sql_err(msg) 
char *msg; 
{ 
char err_msg[128]; 
int  msg_len;     
/*hy   strcpy (err_msg, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);  */ 
   msg_len = strlen (err_msg); 
   fprintf(logfp, "error %s\n", err_msg); 
   /* exec sql ROLLBACK; */ 

{ 
   struct sqlexd sqlstm; 
   sqlstm.sqlvsn = 10; 
   sqlstm.arrsiz = 2; 
   sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt; 
   sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds; 
   sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1; 
   sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )100; 
   sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0; 
   sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca; 
   sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)256; 
   sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0; 
   sqlcxt((void **)0, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn); 
   if (sqlca.sqlcode < 0) sql_err("Debug 1\n"); 
} 


   return (IAPFAIL); 
} 
/*******************************************************************/ 
/*******************************************************************/ 

fmt_clnt version is HY2009Q4 
High batch is 20091224 
Only 8 entries in table but will loop forever 
For (;;) loop change to max 20 to force breaking out 
When i=1 sqlcode=0 sub_code=0 desc=Normal submission                                           
When i=2 sqlcode=0 sub_code=A desc=Requested pre-approval claim                                
When i=3 sqlcode=0 sub_code=C desc=Subscriber coverage problem                                 
When i=4 sqlcode=0 sub_code=D desc=Duplicate claim                                             
When i=5 sqlcode=0 sub_code=I desc=ICBC claim                                                  
When i=6 sqlcode=0 sub_code=R desc=Re-submitted claim
```

Comment: I think your log got cut off, there are only 6 entries. Unless it is working correctly>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know zero Pro*C, but I believe the most commonly accepted syntax is this

```
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break;
for(;;)
  //statement
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND CONTINUE;
```

Also, when checking for a *not found* value I normally check against sqlcode 100, not 1403. I'm not sure what the difference is, but I've seen both.

Comment: I dont think it's the syntax because if I used the original copy of c program to compile and link it would just work fine. Yes I noticed the log got cutoff I will post the entire log again.

Comment: The sql code can vary between those two values depending on whether one is in ansi mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your original fmt_clnt.pc file you have a chunk of code following:

```
/* exec sql INCLUDE sqlca; */
```

This code should be removed and replaced with:

```
#include <sqlca.h>
```

The code you have in the file is built around the previous version and may have subtle changes in the structures. This is especially true when you go from one major version to another or Oracle.

Comment: I removed the chunk or codes and put the sqlca.h back but it's doing the same thing. Still pretty sure it's the pre-compiler so I am going to post the options I used may be that would help.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still interested:
I have finally resolved the issue by building a clean pc then installing an old version of the precompiler. 
Comparing the 2 outputs it seems the datatype for the sqlca.sqlcode is causing the problem.
Pro*c ver 2.2 sqlcode is long while pro*c ver 9.0 is integer. This would explain why I was always getting a zero returned.
Thanks to all who contributed.